# Python Pygame Enemy Collision

Tags: python, pygame

I have a pygame game in the works, the problem is i want when player collides with lvl1a and or lvl1b, they are destroyed, and the player gets bigger. How would i accomplish this? I know i would have to redraw the scene but when i tried that the lvl1a and lvl1b wouldnt go away...

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os
import random
import pygame
import math
import sys

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"

winw = 600
winh = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((winw, winh))
pygame.display.set_caption(" Charger V1 Lvl1")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player1 = pygame.rect.Rect(32, 32, 24, 24)
rect1 = pygame.rect.Rect(550, 550, 16, 16)
rect2 = pygame.rect.Rect(500, 850, 16, 16)

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = player1

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-2, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(2, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, -2)
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, 2)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 128), self.rect)

class Lvl1a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = rect1
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def move(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (100, 100, 100), self.rect)

class Lvl1b(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = rect2
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def move(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (100, 100, 100), self.rect)

pygame.init()

player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
lvl1a = Lvl1a()
lvl1b = Lvl1b()

running = True       
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           break
           running = False

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    lvl1b.draw(screen)
    lvl1b.move()
    lvl1a.draw(screen)
    player.draw(screen)
    lvl1a.move()
    player.handle_keys()
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(40)
```

Comment: stop drawing & moving the elements in the while loop?!? once the collision happens you need to remove the elements from the refresh cycle.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean? could you show me exactly in a reply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll need to make a way for the player to collide with the enemy rects with pygame.Rect.colliderect(). The documentation on Rect.colliderect() is [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect).

To do this, you could add a new function to your player class that looks like this:

```
def collide(self,enemy,enemy_list):
    if self.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):  # Tests if the player is touching an enemy
        enemy_list.remove(enemy)  # Removes the enemy from the enemy list (Explained lower)
```

what you could then do is put the enemies in a list, and have them be rendered with a for loop like this:

```
lvl1a = Lvl1a()
lvl1b = Lvl1b()
enemies = [lvl1a,lvl1b]
```

Then use a for loop to render them within the main loop:

```
for enemy in enemies:  # Runs through the enemy list
    enemy.move()  # Moves the enemy
    player.collide(enemy,enemies)  # Checks if enemy is touching player
    enemy.draw(screen)  # Renders Enemies in the list
```

In this way, when the player collides with an enemy, the enemy is removed from the list of enemies, and will not be rendered anymore.

I hope this helps. If you aren't getting anything, post a comment, and I'll see if I can clarify my answer a bit. :)

---

The fixed code should look something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os
import random
import pygame
import math
import sys

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"

winw = 600
winh = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((winw, winh))
pygame.display.set_caption(" Charger V1 Lvl1")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player1 = pygame.rect.Rect(32, 32, 24, 24)
rect1 = pygame.rect.Rect(550, 550, 16, 16)
rect2 = pygame.rect.Rect(500, 850, 16, 16)

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = player1

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-2, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(2, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, -2)
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
           self.rect.move_ip(0, 2)

    def collide(self,enemy,enemy_list):
        if self.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):  # Tests if the player is touching an enemy
            enemy_list.remove(enemy)  # Removes the enemy from the enemy list (Explained lower)           

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 128), self.rect)

class Lvl1a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = rect1
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def move(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (100, 100, 100), self.rect)

class Lvl1b(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = rect2
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def move(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -1)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (100, 100, 100), self.rect)

pygame.init()

player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
lvl1a = Lvl1a()
lvl1b = Lvl1b()
enemies = [lvl1a,lvl1b]  # Create the enemies list

running = True       
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           break
           running = False

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    for enemy in enemies:  # Runs through the enemy list
        enemy.move()  # Moves the enemy
        player.collide(enemy,enemies)  # Checks if enemy is touching player
        enemy.draw(screen)  # Renders Enemies in the list

    player.draw(screen)
    player.handle_keys()
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(40)
```

Comment: when i collide the player with the enemies, it just pauses for a second then they keep moving..

Comment: @AKcoArts Did you remove the `lvl1a.move()` and `.draw()` and the `lvl1b.move()` and `.draw()` that is not in the for loop out of the main loop? I'm going to also edit my answer with the fixed code, so you can see where it may be going wrong.